# Read a text file and display each entry on one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I want to read a text file and display the info in a div, and then replace the separator `|` with a `<br/>` so everything is on one line. I have it working fine so far but the `.replace()` only works once. I read up about this but couldn't figure how to solve it.

Here is my code so far:

```
    $.get('feed.txt', function(data) {
        $('div').html(data.replace('|','<br>'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a regex replace instead of a string replace:

```
.replace(/\|/g, '<br>');
```

note, you have to escape the '|' character.

Comment: Hi this method only puts one <br> above all the info. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this way and it only replaces the first instance of "|"

Comment: Hey, this works .replace(/\|/g, '<br>'). Edit yr answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted your answer but don't worry I up voted it :)